# How can I display a custom value from eav_attribute_option in attributes options?

Tags: magento, attributes, html-table, entity, entity-attribute-value

Here I have 2 custom columns in the table 'eav_attribute_option':

[image: eav_attribute_option table]

And I want to display this values here:

[image: on the 2 last fields ('Cor' and 'Usar Cor')]

So, this is my input 'cor'

```
'<td class="a-center"><input name="option[color][{{id}}]" value="'**DISPLAY COLOR VALUE HERE**'" class="color {required:false}" style="max-width:60px;"><\/td>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, in my block i have a foreach with the values of attributes, than i send it to the phtml file.